# Perform multiple fisher.test for groups in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I would like to perform multiple `fisher.test()` for each `tax` and each column (ABCB1 and ABL1 in the example below) in the data frame below.
The contingency tables should be extracted from the rows like shown below.

EDIT:

The contingency table should be calculated as shown below in the example:

```
   data_frame(c(42,1),c(20,3))
```

contingency example:

```
             ABCB1      NotABCB1
tax1Present      42     1
tax1NotPresent   20     3



42 is 43-1
1 is the cell value Present:tax1Present
20 is 23-3
3 is the cell value in NotPresent: tax1NotPresent
```

data:

```
structure(list(group = c("tax1Present", "tax1NotPresent", "tax2Present", 
"tax2NotPresent", "tax3Present", "tax3NotPresent", "tax4Present", 
"tax4NotPresent", "tax5Present", "tax5NotPresent"), ABCB1 = c(1L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 3, 2, 6L), ABL1 = c(18L, 14, 12L, 
9L, 1L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 0L), Present = c(43L, 43, 23L, 23, 
9L, 9, 7L, 7, 20, 20L),NotPresent = c(23, 23, 18, 18, 
7L, 7L, 10L, 10L, 10, 10L), tax = c("tax1", "tax1", "tax2", 
"tax2", "tax3", "tax3", "tax4", "tax4", "tax5", "tax5")), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")


> df
            group ABCB1 ABL1 Present NotPresent  tax
1     tax1Present     1   18    43   23          tax1
2  tax1NotPresent     3   14    43   23          tax1
3     tax2Present     4   12    23   18         tax2
4  tax2NotPresent     5    9    23   18          tax2
5     tax3Present     3    1    9    7         tax3
6  tax3NotPresent     6    5    9    7        tax3
7     tax4Present     6    0    7    10         tax4
8  tax4NotPresent     3    0    7    10         tax4
9     tax5Present     2   7    20   10          tax5
10 tax5NotPresent     6    0    20   10          tax5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using apply:

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(group = c("tax1Present", "tax1NotPresent", "tax2Present", 
"tax2NotPresent", "tax3Present", "tax3NotPresent", "tax4Present", 
"tax4NotPresent", "tax5Present", "tax5NotPresent"), ABCB1 = c(1L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 12L, 13L, 6L), ABL1 = c(18, 14, 12, 9, 
1, 5, 0, 0, 7, 0), Present = c(43, 43, 23, 23, 9, 9, 7, 7, 20, 
20), NotPresent = c(23, 23, 18, 18, 7, 7, 1, 13, 10, 10), tax = c("tax1", 
"tax1", "tax2", "tax2", "tax3", "tax3", "tax4", "tax4", "tax5", 
"tax5")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
# set the columns to use
columns <- c("ABCB1", "ABL1")

dat_test <- sapply( column, function(colx) 
  lapply( unique(df$tax), function(x) 
    fisher.test( data.frame( 
      a=c(( df[ which(df$tax %in% x)[1] ,"Present"] - 
      df[ which(df$tax %in% x)[1], colx] ), df[ which(df$tax %in% x)[1], colx]), 
      b=c(( df[ which(df$tax %in% x)[2],"NotPresent"] - 
      df[ which(df$tax %in% x)[2], colx] ), df[ which(df$tax %in% x)[2], colx]) ))
 ) )

# set rownames
rownames(dat_test) <- unique( df$tax )

dat_test
     ABCB1  ABL1  
tax1 List,7 List,7
tax2 List,7 List,7
tax3 List,7 List,7
tax4 List,7 List,7
tax5 List,7 List,7
```

TEST:

```
#p-values == manual calculation [and exactly the same
#values as with previous df$Total]:
     ABCB1      ABL1      
tax1 0.1179487  0.1971581 
tax2 0.4709802  1         
tax3 0.06013986 0.03496503
tax4 1          1         
tax5 1          0.06371942
```

Also see: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/332224/2x2-fisher-exact-test-contingency-tables

Comment: Thanks. Does this work for all columns I want to test, ABCB1, ABL1, and many more?

Comment: Thanks. Does this work for all columns I want to test, ABCB1, ABL1, and many more? I guess your "2" is defining to test the column ABCB1 specifically. Is it possible to loop through all columns between column 2 and the second last column?

Comment: Check the update. Added functionality to define columns.

Comment: Made a small update to the names. Also check the results to make sure its what you expected!

Comment: Not sure about the results. Previous you outputted the fisher test results, what does the List, 7 means?

Comment: Same, but for more columns. Check with `dat_test[1,1] etc`

Comment: Understand! thx

Comment: Seems to be something wrong with the p-values. Not sure what...Does not agree with my manual testing of specific comparisons. Maybe the contingency tables are not correct

Comment: I checked some values. They list should be consistent with calculating it manually. I add some in the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239226/discussion-between-user2300940-and-andre-wildberg).

Comment: Take a look at my edit "New test" at the very bottom.

Comment: The test is correct, but the extraction of values is not. Please see updated question.

Comment: What you changed in the question is the transform of what was calculated before. Which is the same as before. Did you see it in my "New test"? If there's still doubt I am going to delete my answer since I seem to not understand the ground problem. Let me know how to proceed.

Comment: Instead of the column Total, we now have the two columns Present and NotPresent. The ABCB1 column is calculated by Present - ABCB1. The NotABCB1 is calculated by NotPresent - NotPresent. So the script needs to be updated to take into account these subtractions.

Comment: I've seen that. But this changes nothing about the doubt that the values have been wrong before. The added columns just add redundancy, "Total" alone was perfectly fine. I going to adjust the script to the new data, but the results will be the same.

Comment: The data df you show is inconsistent with the structure you give. Please update.

Comment: corrected this now

Comment: The data is invalid, has negative values.

Comment: Corrected again. Sorry

Comment: Thanks. [1] and [2] is defining the columns? And rows are selected by gripping for "Present"? The point is that for each pair of rows (tax1, tax2 etc) Subtractions should happen on that specific row, not across rows.

Comment: I finally solved it I thing. Just had to switch inside a and b. Thanks a lot.